# Does UDP's lack of congestion control clog up the Internet?

Tags: internet, udp, speed, congestion

I'm reading *Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach*, and from what I understand, UDP has no widely adopted mechanism for congestion control like TCP does. Isn't this a problem for the Internet as a whole, considering that [the upcoming HTTP/3](https://kinsta.com/blog/http3/) is based on UDP?

I found DCCP, but [it is not widely adopted](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-amend-tsvwg-dccp-udp-header-conversion-01).

And I know congestion control can be implemented in the application layer, but why would an individual choose to do that, if no one is required to? Congestion control seems like something that is good for everyone if everyone does it. But it is not required, and it seems that a few people doing it on their own only results in their application being slower without any noticeable benefit to the Internet, if everyone else doesn't care about congestion control because they just want the highest speeds for themselves individually... which results in a slower Internet for all. This seems like it will be a problem as UDP is more widely used in the future.

Am I off in my understanding of this?

Comment: Actually, a lot of streaming is TCP.

Comment: @RonTrunk Thanks for the correction! I was confusing live streaming video, with streaming video in general. I've edited out my incorrect remark on streaming video using UDP.

Comment: Why do you think having an application or application-layer protocol on UDP resend lost data any more problematic than having TCP (or any other reliable transport protocol) do the same thing?

Comment: @RonMaupin I am under the impression that when a network is congested, TCP lowers the sending rate, whereas UDP may keep resending at a high rate, which only worsens the congestion. Is that correct? I know that in reality TCP is not always used so kindly, for example when web browsers use parallel TCP connections to download webpage resources more quickly. But at least each connection is limited if there is congestion, whereas UDP may not adjust at all to congestion. Correct me if I'm wrong! I'm new to this.

Comment: But an application or application-layer protocol can do anything TCP does or more or less. IP, on top of which TCP and UDP ride, has no reliability, guarantees, or congestion control, but TCP adds that, and something on top of UDP could add that.

Comment: @RonMaupin Right, those who use UDP have the option of implementing those things. But if they are not *required* to adapt to congestion by resending less frequently, then why would they bother? The benefit of it is collective (if everyone does it), but individually there is no benefit to doing it, and in fact my application will be slower with congestion control, than without it. So if it's optional for everyone, wouldn't everyone naturally just not do it, unless they came to some agreement that forced everyone to do it?

Comment: "_in fact my application will be slower with congestion control, than without it._ Not necessarily. Having to resend more without congestion control can slow your application much more than using congestion control. "_if it's optional for everyone, wouldn't everyone naturally just not do it, unless they came to some agreement that forced everyone to do it?_" Again, no. It may sometimes be advantageous to not use congestion control, e.g. real-time data, but in those cases you do not want to resend lost data.

Comment: @RonMaupin Aha, that was my fundamental misunderstanding. From the book, I understood that resend-spamming would be faster for an individual application, and that a more cautious approach would only benefit others. But I see that is incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: That's what a lot of programmers on [so] simply do not get, and they want to use UDP (they are under the wrong assumption that data latency is much worse on TCP, even though it really is not; sending a data packet from one host to another has the same latency, it is just the overhead of setting up a TCP connection that takes time), so they try to recreate TCP without really understanding, and it does not go well for them. The many network-savvy programmers there tell them to just use TCP.

Comment: TCP has a couple of major issues one is head of line blocking, one lost packet means everything gets delayed until it's resent. The other is that switching to a different internet connection breaks ongoing sessions. There have been attempts to fix these issues at the transport layer but they have proved difficul to deploy in practice. This is why application level soloutions based on UDP are rising in popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is unreliable and has no guarantees. If you use UDP and want reliability or guarantees, then you must add any reliability or guarantees in the application or application-layer protocol.

Real-time protocols, such as VoIP or video do not want missing data to be resent because it would arrive after it is useful. Such applications and protocols are designed to deal with missing data (to some degree before erroring or timing out). If you can buffer on the end-host (non-real-time), you can use TCP because of the buffer, which is how much video is done.

---

**Edit**:

TCP congestion control is completely determined and handled by the sender based on the fact that it must resend data. Adding reliability to an application or application-layer protocol can also be used for congestion control the same way that TCP does it, or in some other fashion. For example, QUIC (an application-layer protocol on top of UDP) has flow control, and the intention is to improve congestion control and add things like FEC.

---

Unfortunately, until we move to IPv6, we are stuck with only TCP and UDP because of NAPT. Other protocols, such as DCCP or SCTP or other future protocols, are not supported by NAPT.